# Representing loops in a UML activity diagram

Tags: uml

I am trying to design an activity diagram (UML) for a networked tic tac toe game that I developed, with sockets. I am using activity partitions (swimlanes). So, there is three partitions: Client1, Server, and Client2.

The diagram is looking good, except I do not know how to represent loop structures.

If you look at this link: [activity diagram](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html), and look at the last diagram on the page (Partition), that is the type of activity diagram that I am working with.

Does anyone know how I can represent loops? Thanks!

Comment: You need to elaborate on your problem domain.

Comment: UML activity diagram might able to explain loops - in a procedural way. But I can see a shortage what UML will fail to describe functional expression like (map/foreach/reduce) in a simply way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look further down the [page you link to](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html) for Expansion Region.  Use one with the iterative keyword.

> An expansion region is a structured activity region that executes multiple times. Input and output expansion nodes are drawn as a group of three boxes representing a multiple selection of items. The keyword "iterative", "parallel" or "stream" is shown in the top left corner of the region.

Comment: That caught my eye, but I am unsure of how to use that. Do you know of any other example diagrams that uses this?

Comment: I don't have anything non-proprietary that I could show at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but why not just using the exit flow of the last activity in the loop as input flow for the first activity in the loop (with a guard condition to finish the loop when appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a set of data for the input, then the "Expansion Region" is perfect.
For instance, you want to convert in Euro all your incomes. Then, it's like a for().

But if you want to have something similar to a while(), you must use rounded rectangle and diamonds, with a feedback loop.

For instance: ***[Play blackjack] ->if I win --> I stop ->else --> i start again***.

I think that the only efficient ways to do loop in an activity diagram.

You can have a look at the [loop node](http://www.gentleware.com/fileadmin/media/archives/userguides/poseidon_users_guide/activitydiagram.html). But I'm not sure how well defined it is in the OMG spec.